# Linking Screens in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am new to Blackberry devlopment and i have created 3 screens for the Blackberry application. Now my question is how to link these screens like if iam on 1st screen and if i click a button like submit it should go to the next screen like this it should go from 2nd screen to 3rd screens.
thanks

Comment: How about not screaming the question and using some punctuation?

Answer (score 2):

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(yourNextScreen);
```

See the [documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html?net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html) on RIM website.

Answer (score 1):

You add a listener (I have given code for the trackwheelClick listener below, but you can use others as well depending on if you want a keypress or touch etc.

I have written in the matter of implementing the event on the instantiated object itself, but you can also subclass ButtonField if you really want to.

```
    ButtonField closeButton = new ButtonField("Close") {
        public boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NextScreen());
            return true;
        }

    };
```